# Replace an object in object tree

Tags: javascript

I need to replace an object from in object tree, I tried several methods but I couldn't

```
let data = [
    {
      "accountId": 2
    }, 
    {
      "accountId": 6,
      "children": [{
        "accountId": 8
      }]
    }, 
    {
      "accountId": 45
    }
];
```

In above object array I need to replace ( when I know the `accoundId` )

```
{
  "accountId": 2
}
```

to

```
{
  "accountId": 2,
  "children": [
    {
      "accountId": 85
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way(s)/library(s) to do that.

Comment: How are you getting the `children`? Some logic or hard coded data?

Comment: yes, its represent the children accounts (sub account) api send the data object like that

Comment: Not clear. How are you are getting the value 85?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain javascript, using `Array.prototype.map` function:

```js
var data = [{ "accountId": 2 }, { "accountId": 6, "children": [{ "accountId": 8 }] }, { "accountId": 45 }];

var newData = { "accountId": 2, "children": [{ "accountId": 85 }] };

data = (function upd(data, n) {
    return data.map(e => {
        if (e.children) {
            var o = {};
            o.accountId = e.accountId;
            o.children = upd(e.children, n);
            return o;
        }
        else if (e.accountId == 8) {
            return n;
        } else return e;
    });
})(data, newData);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Yes it is, but this not working If I want to replace `accountId = 8` that inside child account array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iterative function for the search for the id and update of the array item.

```js
function makeUpdate(a, u) {
    return Array.isArray(a) && a.some(function (b,i,bb) {
        if (b.accountId === u.accountId) {
            bb[i] = u;
            return true;
        }
        return makeUpdate(b.children, u);
    });
}

var data = [{ "accountId": 2 }, { "accountId": 6, "children": [{ "accountId": 8 }] }, { "accountId": 45 }],
    update = { "accountId": 8, "children": [{ "accountId": 85 }] };

makeUpdate(data, update);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```